# How can I compile a C console program using Cairo library (that compiles ok on Ubuntu) on Windows 11?

Tags: c, windows, compilation, cairo

I made a console C program that reads a .obj 3d model and unflatten it into a multipage PDF. At first I used a little PDF library (https://github.com/AndreRenaud/PDFGen) that worked fine and I was able to compile my code on Windows 11, but I needed to have text rotated and it wasn't possible with PDFGen, so I changed for Cairo Library (https://github.com/freedesktop/cairo). With Cairo my code does exactly what I want, but I didn't find how to compile it on Windows.

I'm using Geany to edit/compile my C code, my build command is :

```
gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f"  -lcairo -lm
```

I tried to do the same on Geany on Windows and it didn't work.
I found a repository with standalone cairo DLL for Windows, but didn't manage to use it.
I'm looking for another PDF library that could be used both on Linux and Windows, but for the moment didn't find any.

my code is here (https://github.com/gilboonet/Deplieur-C/blob/main/deplieur.c)

It's my first post here, I'm a long time C programmer but not IT pro and I'm not a Windows user, I only want to compile my code on it because lots of people that will use my program are windows users. Thank you.

Comment: @KJ Thank you for those two solutions, mupdf api would have been a great replacement for Cairo, but I didn't manage to use it for the moment. For an prior web version of this project I used node.js code to create a PDF from a text file, so it's something I can manage. I will try to make it with C Sharp as I have working .cs that creates a PDF and is cross-platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a project called ["cairo-windows"](https://github.com/preshing/cairo-windows) on Github that creates resources needed to build a C project using Cairo, and it works, even if I needed to use Visual Studio. Sadly, it seems to have problem with pdf creation that only creates a blank file. To make it work I changed the resources (dll and includes) it needs to build the project to those from my gtk windows build it comes with Cairo 1.16.0. If you want to do the same, you must replace the extern directory from cairo-windows (initially fetched by setup-win32.py): lib by cairo.lib, cairo.dll expat.dll fontconfig-1.dll freetype-6.dll and libpng16.dll from your gtk build (..gtk\x64\release\bin) and include by the content of ..\gtk\x64\include.

Comment: I ran the same project on Linux and it correctly created the PDF, I also changed it on Windows to create a SVG file and it worked, so I suspect that there is something missing on the cairo.dll used on Winwows or something like that.

Comment: I finally manage to make it work by replacing the dll and includes that cairo-windows need by files from my gtk windows build and it creates the pdf. There was a memory leak with the latest 1.17.4 cairo version and with the 1.16.0 it's ok.